# Compose io cant connect to Mongo Compass

Tags: mongodb, compose-db, mongodb-compass

Using compose.io with a MongoDB it does have SSL. 
when copying the URI string i go into Compass and am prompted to fill in details from a string which I do, when trying to connect I get this error message.

```
Could not connect to MongoDB on the provided host and port
```

any idea why it cant connect? if I use a different provider like Atlas for the MongoDB and do the same steps it works fine, so I'm guessing maybe its a setting from compose.io? they said that it should just work which it's unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find your answer in this freshly published blog here https://www.compose.com/articles/how-to-connect-mongodb-compass-to-compose/

It covers setting up SSL with the certificate provided.

Comment: I came to this article trying to connect Compass to my MongoDB instance created through Heroku. Where is the "Show Certificate" button? The "SSL Certificate (Self-Signed) panel" does not exist. I could not view my data with SSL: Off.

Comment: If you can't see the certificate, it's probably because your deployment has been set up with Let's Encrypt certificates. Just set the SSL field in Compass to System CA/Atlas.

Comment: Could you please update your link(blog post) to include this. I switched back to the mLab instance because I couldn't resolve this issue.